# How to modify selected UITexFiled value in Array of Textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield

Currently, I created Array of `UITextField` based on Response from Server in my UI, My response contains three types of response in single API, i.e I get 5 key and Values. Values contains Types like String, Date, Array, based on this when I select the `UITextFiled` the value must change according to that Particular TextFiled

**Here my Sample Code:**

```
   for (int i=0;i<itemAttributeArray.count;i++){
        UIColor *floatingLabelColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        textField1 = [[JVFloatLabeledTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, y, width, height)];
        textField1.delegate = self;
        //Set tag 101
        textField1.tag = 101;
        NSLog(@"textField1.tag - %ld",(long)textField1.tag);
        textField1.text = [[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"value"]objectAtIndex:i];
        [self SetTextFieldBorder:textField1];
        textField1.placeholder = [keyArr objectAtIndex:i];

        textField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kJVFieldFontSize];
        //            textField1.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
        textField1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

        textField1.floatingLabelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kJVFieldFloatingLabelFontSize];
        textField1.floatingLabelTextColor = floatingLabelColor;

  //      textField1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];

        [_scroll addSubview:textField1];
        [textFields addObject:textField1];
        [textField1 release];

        y += height + margin;

        if ([[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"string"]){
            NSLog(@"type - %@",[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i]);

        }else if ([[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] 
 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"date"]){
   NSLog(@"type - %@",[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i]);
            textField1.tag = 102;
            [textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange_dateChek)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
        }else if ([[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"double"]){
             NSLog(@"type - %@",[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i]);
        }

-(void)textFieldDidChange_dateChek{
NSLog(@"iam called on first edit");
 _picker_uiView.hidden = false;
[_datePickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}



 - (void)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

   textField1.text = [dateFormatter 
  stringFromDate:_datePickerView.date];
   }
```

When I select the date value is entered in the last object to UITextfield but I selected index is 2nd but values changing on the last element of UITextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are create the textfield in globally, thats the reason you get the last index only. in here assign the tag for each textfield as well as create the instance value.for e.g

```
 for (int i=0;i<itemAttributeArray.count;i++){
        UIColor *floatingLabelColor = [UIColor brownColor];
       JVFloatLabeledTextField *textField1 = [[JVFloatLabeledTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, y, width, height)];
        textField1.delegate = self;
        //Set tag 101
        textField1.tag = 101 + i;
        NSLog(@"textField1.tag - %ld",(long)textField1.tag);
        textField1.text = [[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"value"]objectAtIndex:i];
        [self SetTextFieldBorder:textField1];
        textField1.placeholder = [keyArr objectAtIndex:i];

        textField1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kJVFieldFontSize];
        //            textField1.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
        textField1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

        textField1.floatingLabelFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kJVFieldFloatingLabelFontSize];
        textField1.floatingLabelTextColor = floatingLabelColor;

  //      textField1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];

        [_scroll addSubview:textField1];
        [textFields addObject:textField1];
        [textField1 release];

        y += height + margin;

        if ([[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"string"]){
            NSLog(@"type - %@",[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i]);

        }else if ([[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"date"]){
  NSLog(@"type - %@",[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i]);



            [textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange_dateChek:)
                         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
        }else if ([[[itemAttributeArray valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"double"]){

        }
              }
```

**and handle the textfield action**

```
  -(void)textFieldDidChange_dateChek:(JVFloatLabeledTextField*)textfield{
NSLog(@"iam called on first edit");
 _picker_uiView.hidden = false;

_datePickerView.tag = textfield.tag;
[textfield resignFirstResponder];
[_datePickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
textfield.inputView = _datePickerView;
 }
```

finally assign the value to the textfield as like follow

```
- (void)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker*)sender {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
 //  textField1.tag = 102;
for(id aSubView in [_scroll subviews]){
    if([aSubView isKindOfClass:[JVFloatLabeledTextField class]])
    {
          JVFloatLabeledTextField *textFds=(JVFloatLabeledTextField*)aSubView;
        if (textFds.tag == sender.tag) {
             NSLog(@"dad == %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date]);
            textFds.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date];
            [textFds resignFirstResponder];
            [sender removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }

        }
}
```